# Memory Card Information

Tags: .net, media, removable-storage

I'm detecting the insertion of memory cards (removable media). Can I get information about the inserted media - type, manufacturer, etc?

Comment: Out of interest, how are you detecting the insertion?  Polling or something better?

Comment: Overriding WndProc to receive the notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to use WMI to query the [Win32_PhysicalMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346(VS.85).aspx) type and get the information you want.

Here is a basic code example of how to do a general query on the class:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

foreach (ManagementObject wmiObject in searcher.Get())
{
    if (wmiObject["Manufacturer"] == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(wmiObject["Manufacturer"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I know how to use WMI in .NET :) Unfortunately, the class didn't expose any information regarding the memory card.

Comment: @John - What about Win32_PhysicalMemory?